# Way to read first few lines for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Is there a built-in way to use `read_csv` to read only the first `n` lines of a file without knowing the length of the lines ahead of time? I have a large file that takes a long time to read, and occasionally only want to use the first, say, 20 lines to get a sample of it (and prefer not to load the full thing and take the head of it).

If I knew the total number of lines I could do something like `footer_lines = total_lines - n` and pass this to the `skipfooter` keyword arg. My current solution is to manually grab the first `n` lines with python and StringIO it to pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

n = 20
with open('big_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    head = ''.join(f.readlines(n))

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(head))
```

It's not that bad, but is there a more concise, 'pandasic' (?) way to do it with keywords or something?

Comment: To see how to load the last _N_ lines checkout [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108250/efficiently-read-last-n-rows-of-csv-into-dataframe)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

I think you can use the `nrows` parameter.  From [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
nrows : int, default None

    Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files
```

which seems to work.  Using one of the standard large test files (988504479 bytes, 5344499 lines):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: time z = pd.read_csv("P00000001-ALL.csv", nrows=20)
CPU times: user 0.00 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 0.00 s
Wall time: 0.00 s

In [3]: len(z)
Out[3]: 20

In [4]: time z = pd.read_csv("P00000001-ALL.csv")
CPU times: user 27.63 s, sys: 1.92 s, total: 29.55 s
Wall time: 30.23 s
```

Comment: `skiprows=None` is also a useful parameter to remember

Comment: What's the best way to load the last n rows? Basically what tail() does, but I need to use it while loading the csv. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DanailPetrov:  Use `skiprows`, something like `df = pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=total_rows - n, nrows=n)`

Comment: can you elaborate on that? What is `total_rows` in this case? Custom function?

Answer (score 5):

I would use 'skiprows' argument in read_csv, e.g.,:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=range(2, 20000), nrows=10000)
```