# Python: import selected rows of dataframe. My data is in xlsx format

Tags: python

Hi everybody I am beginner at machine learning in Python environment and I want to import only the first 30-40 rows of dataframe which has 30.000 rows for development.Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Import from where? which libraries are you using?

Comment: I am using panda I tried pd.Excelfile command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to read first few lines for pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008970/way-to-read-first-few-lines-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I want to import only the first 30 rows from excel to python=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pandas.read_csv 'nrows' parameter, like this:

```
pd.read_csv(myFilePath, nrows=30)
```

nrows : int, default None
Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files

Full documentation can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

If you want to do it after you read all the file:

```
DataFrame.head(n=30)
```